# How to Save Decimal Without Rounding in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, numbers, decimal, rounding

I have a program that save amount that is inserted by user

here is the function to save the amount inserted by user

```
Protected Sub btn_Submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Submit.Click

    If Not Page.IsValid Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim objNewAmount As New Amount

    If Not objCurrAmount Is Nothing Then
        objNewAmount.AmountID = objCurrAmount.AmountID
        isUpdate = True
    End If

    objNewAmount.AmountName = txtAmountName.Text
    Dim amount As Double = txtAmount.Text
    objNewAmount.Amount= amount

    Dim IsError As Boolean = False
    Try
        objNewAmount.AmountName.UpdateAmount()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblInfo.Text = ex.Message
        IsError = True
    End Try
    If Not IsError Then
        Response.Redirect("AmountList.aspx", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then when I insert the amount of 2,32 I expected it to save 2,32 but instead it save 232 instead without the separator

Data type for the amount is decimal(18,2) in database and decimal in vb code class

This is my snippet of class of Amount
objNewAmount is

```
Private _Tarif As Decimal = 0
Public Property Tarif() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Tarif
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _Tarif = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Can anyone help me,

Snippet for UpdateAmount()

```
strSQL.Append(" begin" & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("  " & GetNewShortIDQuery("m_Amount", "AmountID", "JH", "@NewID", 6, 4) & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("  insert into m_Amount" & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   select @NewID" & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , " & ReplaceQuota(AmountName) & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , " & ReplaceQuota(Amount, "num") & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , " & ReplaceQuota(CreatorID) & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , " & ReplaceQuota(CreatorIP) & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , " & ReplaceQuota(CreatorDateTime, "datetime") & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , null" & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , null" & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append("   , null;" & vbCrLf)
        strSQL.Append(" end" & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: What's the data type of `objNewAmount.Amount`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i save it as decimal(18,2)

Comment: @topsail i save it as decimal(18,2)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter how you save it. The question is what is the datatype of the thing you are saving. For example, if you save an `int` as a `decimal(18,2)`, it will never have fractional values in the decimal part.

Comment: You're telling us the data type of a column in the database. That's not the question we asked. We asked you what the data type is of a field/property in your VB code. Read the actual words and answer the question we asked.

Comment: @topsail i'm sorry if i get it wrong or my answer didn't match your expected answer, at first i save it as integer, now i save it as decimal in vb code class

Comment: Is `UpdateAmount()` also code you wrote?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm sorry if i get it wrong or my answer didn't match your expected answer i'm really trying my best to answer, in the vb code class i save it as integer before but i've changed it to decimal now, but it won't save the decimal, for example, now I try to save 2,32 it become 232 instead, i've also tried saving by changing the comma to point 2.32 but still comes out as 232

Comment: @topsail ok wait let me update my question

Comment: Think it might be helpful if you post the class definition of objNewAmount maybe.  You've got an Amount property on that object, we want to see how that is declared.  Slight sight, but may help nail down root cause.  Put _Option Strict On_ at the top of your code file, heaps of explainers about that on the internet what that does and why use it

Comment: @Hursey yes thank you for your information, i've learned my mistake, turns out i haven't written the question with enough information, I've updated my question though, sorry for the hassle

Comment: You should absolutely not be building your SQL code that way. You should learn how to do it properly, using parameters. I'd wager that that would "fix" this issue by making it a non-issue. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on the subject.

Comment: Umm.... yeah, not really updated it with the right information though.  Show use the definition of objNewAmount, that way we see the type for the Amount property.  And I also completely agree with other comments on how your constructing the SQL

Comment: Have you inspected the `strSQL` that you are generating, before the command is executed on the database? Its hard to tell from that code what would result because it itself is now calling other functions that are not visible to us (although agree - shouldn't be done that way at all, use parameters instead).

Comment: @topsail I did print out how the strSQL looks though it print out 232 instead of 2.32 or 2,32 now

Comment: It seems that the problem is in your code that turns your data into raw sql, before it ever gets to the database.

Comment: @topsail do you mean it removes any special char from my data before inserting it?

Comment: Not sure exactly - you should be testing your UpdateAmount() method to figure out why you give it `2.32` (assuming you are actually giving it this value), and it creates a sql to insert `232`. There are two additional functions in there that need exploration, one called `GetNewShortIDQuery()` and another called `GetQuota()`. Also you need to verify that all of the variables that are being used in this code snippet are what you expect them to be when the code snippet executes.

Comment: @topsail thank you for your help but I found out that even without my getquota() function i still can't insert the decimal in point or comma, so I've decided to use varchar instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all @topsail @Hursey and @jmcilhinney for your help
I've resorted to using varchar since if I use decimal when ever I use comma it can't be inserted and if I use point it will be gone instead

So i've decided to change the data type into varchar so it can be inserted to the database and since it doesn't interfere with the calculation

Comment: So you cured the *symptom*, not the *cause*. That's always a _bad_ choice. I highly recommend to take a look at the @jmcilhinney posted and use parameters.